# How to write a shell script that allows the user to enter X amount of password attempts within 5 minutes?

Tags: shell, terminal, password-protection

How do you write a shell script that allows the user to enter X amount of password attempts within 5 minutes or it will log the user off?

So far I have this:

```
    trap 'echo do not mess with this computer' 1 2 3 9 15 18
stty -echo

echo "key:"
read key1
echo "again"
read key2
key3=
if [ "$key1" = "$key2" ]
then
 tput clear

until [ "$key3" = "$key1" ]
do
echo "enter the key"
read key3
done

else echo "try again"
fi

stty echo
```

Comment: The shell is not where you'd do this.

Comment: Ya. For security reason, you shouldn't do it in a shell script.

Comment: @RobinHsu but this is an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question, you can add delay to failed SSH login but you don't do that by a script.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105553/how-to-provide-login-delay-in-ssh